# Hibernate click event binding with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, binding

I a code similar to the following

```
$(element).click(function() {
$(slider).slide();
});
```

What I want to do is to deactivate the click event until the sliding finish (or more precisely the function complete) so that users don't abuse it. How can I do that?

Comment: Like @Dimitri said, there isn't any `slide()` animation in jQuery [UI]. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: I'm using my own function; But that shouldn't matter. consider it as a simple function that takes time to execute.

Comment: Actually, it *does* matter - as Dimitri said, most jQuery animation functions have a callback which tells you when the animation is finished. That's what he's trying to make use of also in his answer. Can you post the `slide()` code also please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/8u2KP/

The trick is to check if

`if (!$('#slider').is(':animated')) {//CODE HERE}`

Answer (score 1):

Something has to trigger sliding, so deactivating won't be an option. Instead you could start sliding on click and perform whatever other operations you need to in the slide()'s callback function:

```
$(element).click(function() {
    $(slider).slide(function(){ // Do something additional here});
});
```

Hope i understood your question right.

P.S. Not quite sure if jquery has slide() effect. It sure has slideToggle, slideUp and slideDown, but haven't heard of slide

Try the below code for your purposes.

```
$(element).click(function() {
    $(element).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(slider).slide(function(){ $(element).removeAttr("disabled"); });
});
```

Comment: I think my question was clear: I want to disable the click event, so that the user doesn't slide the slider until the last sliding finish :)

Comment: but you do want the click to be enabled before toggling the slide?